# Cloning an object to view when editing with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I follow this tutorial on WPF MVVM

https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/21.2.php

It's in russian, but basically the viewmodel contains a list of `Phone` objects and the tutorial teaches how to implement Add/Remove/Delete Commands to the list of `Phone` with writing the changes to the database. Here's the `EditCommand` Command:

```
public RelayCommand EditCommand
{
    get
    {
        return editCommand ??
            (editCommand = new RelayCommand((selectedItem) =>
            {
                if (selectedItem == null) return;
                Phone phone = selectedItem as Phone;
 
                Phone vm = new Phone()
                {
                    Id = phone.Id,
                    Company = phone.Company,
                    Price = phone.Price,
                    Title = phone.Title
                };
                PhoneWindow phoneWindow = new PhoneWindow(vm);
 
                if (phoneWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    phone = db.Phones.Find(phoneWindow.Phone.Id);
                    if (phone != null)
                    {
                        phone.Company = phoneWindow.Phone.Company;
                        phone.Title = phoneWindow.Phone.Title;
                        phone.Price = phoneWindow.Phone.Price;
                        db.Entry(phone).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
        }));
    }
}
```

Here, author copies properties one by one from `selectedItem` to the `vm` object and later from `phoneWindow` to the database model.

The problem is, in the project I'm working on, instead of a simple class `Phone` I use complex class with many nested types and nested lists. Do I have to copy them all by hand 2 times? How can I automate it?

Comment: _"Do I have to copy them all by hand"_ -- maybe, maybe not. That depends on the objects, and your question lacks specific details along those lines. If they are mutable objects and you want to capture the current state of the object, keeping the copy exactly as-is even if the other changes, you'll need to deep-clone the object. See duplicate. If you want the copy to reflect changes, no copy is needed, just use the same reference. Likewise if the objects are immutable, you don't need to worry because there won't ever be a change to the object.

Answer (score 0):

To easily map one object to another you can use a mapper library to do the heavy work for you, like [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/).

All you have to do is configure the mappings you will need during startup:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>());
```

Then call `Map()` on the object:

```
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
// or
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
OrderDto dto = mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);
```

More info [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html)